# How to properly stub a function within a function module using sinon in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testing, stubbing

I keep trying to stub this function within a module in a format like so (myModule.js):

```
module.exports = function (config) {

    setUpModule(config);

    async function myFunction(parameters) {
        // logic...
    }

    return {
        myFunction,
    };
}
```

In my tests, I try to stub it like:

```
`beforeEach(() => {
    myFunctionStub = sinon.stub(myModule, 'myFunction').resolves(['apple', 'orange', 'grape']);
});

afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
});`
```

Yet I keep getting: `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property myFunction`

Am I bringing in the function incorrectly? I have tried using the prototype keyword with the same result.

I have seen examples of using stub this way, and then using the instance of the module created to run tests on. I want to globally stub the function so that when other functions create their own instances of the module and run myFunction, that will return the stubbed value. I am quite new to stubbing with sinon, so maybe I am missing something obvious or misunderstanding the scope of what I can stub here.

I would appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Tried prototype keyword, stubbing as myModule()/myModule().prototype, but cannot get the function to be properly globally stubbed